# Custom post type defaults to index.php for archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, permalinks, templates

I've developed a custom theme with a custom post type named `events`. For some reason, however, WP refuses to use my archive page template with the file name `archive-events.php` per WP's template hierarchy. WP keeps defaulting to `index.php` as the template for this post type.

Previously I had a page configured in WP that was set to the slug `/events/` which is now the slug of the custom post type. That page is now deleted, and I don't know if this is the issue that is causing WP to refuse to use `archive-events.php` for my archive listing for the custom post type. I've tried modifying and re-saving my permalink structure, and that hasn't worked. Currently the permastruct is set to "Post name," i.e. `http://my.domain/post-name/`

More details:

- I've registered a custom post type of `events` (code below)
- The slug of the post type is "events" and individual posts are rendering successfully at `http://domain.com/events/post-name`
- The archive page for the post type is accessible at `/events/` but is using `index.php` even though I've created an archive template for the post type as `archive-events.php`
- To confirm what template WP is using to render the archive page for the custom post type, I've created a function that outputs the `$GLOBALS['current_theme_template']` being used to render the page. This confirms that WP is using `index.php` to render the archive page.
- In my `header.php` file I'm echoing the function `get_post_type_archive_link('events')` to confirm that WP thinks that the archive page for my custom post type should be `http://domain.com/events/`
- The `archive.php` and `index.php` WP templates are served as expected, but the template for the custom post type is skipped by WP no matter what
- As a test, I renamed my existing custom post type to something new, remapped all of my queries to that CPT, and updated my template names accordingly. Still, WP refuses to serve `cpt-archive.php` as the template for the custom post type and serves either `archive.php` or `index.php` instead.

Here's my `functions.php` code to register the post type:

```
function registerEvents()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Events', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Event', 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Events', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'Events', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        <snip>
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'delete_with_user'      => false,
        'supports'              => array( 
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'page-attributes'
        ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'kind' ), // Custom tax previously registered
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'events', 'with_front' => false ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'events', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'registerEvents' );
```

Comment: Does your post type have any posts? And do you have a default archive.php? Because the hierarchy should hit that before the index.

Comment: The custom post type currently has 5 posts. I don't currently use archive.php because I have blog posts that will need to have a different output format. That said, I can try renaming my current custom post type archive page from archive-events.php to archive.php and see what happens.

Comment: Renaming my existing archive-events.php template for the custom post type to archive.php displays a page, but I'll have to recode archive.php completely to fetch posts within the custom post type. I'd still like to understand why WP refuses to use the archive-events.php template per WP's template hierarchy.

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but you said you deleted the old page. Did you empty trash? My first thought was actually that you need to flush your permalinks, but it sounds like you did that already.

Comment: As an experiment, I would try renaming your CPT (eg events2). Rename your custom archive, flush your permalinks, and see if it kicks in. If it does, that would point to the issue being related to the old page address being cached somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the WP trash was emptied for the deleted page type that was using the same slug and permalinks have been changed/flushed/resaved multiple times. I renamed the CPT to something different (newevents), flushed permalinks, created a few new posts in the new CPT, and renamed the existing templates (e.g. archive-newevents.php). WP reports that it expects the archive URL to be /newevents/ as expected. WP simply refuses to use anything other than index.php for the archive page of the CPT! This is WP v5.3.2.

Comment: I copied your code as is and the archive worked fine for me, so there's nothing awry in your code. You could try flushing cache via wp-cli. Worth a shot,

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem turned out to be:

- Changing the name of the custom post type from "events" (with the slug `/events/`) to "event" (with the slug `/event/`)
- Creating a page with a custom template with the slug `/events/` to display the archives of the custom post type

While this is technically not an answer to the question of why WP refuses to serve and display the archive template for the custom post typer per WP's own template hierarchy, it solves my problem.

Along the way, I used wp-cli to flush WP's internal cache and delete all transients, but that didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're registering post types manually (as opposed to using CPT UI or something similar) then you need to remember to go into settings > permalinks and just click 'save'. That's caught me out a couple of times.